# How can I save float arrays in a multiple dimension array in IDL?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am trying to save many float arrays in a multiple dimsensional array. Each float array belongs to a specific index in the dimensional array.

The array size of the float arrays are **[128, 128]**.

**What did I try?**

(I made it simple, right now I am not using the **[128, 128]** size.)

```
multiple_array = MAKE_ARRAY(5, 3, /FLOAT)
> multiple_array
  0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
  0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
  0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000

float_array = FLTARR(3, 3)
;skipped setting some simple values

> float_array
   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000
   4.0000000       5.0000000       6.0000000
   7.0000000       8.0000000       9.0000000

multiple_array[0, 0] = float_array
   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
   4.0000000       5.0000000       6.0000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
   7.0000000       8.0000000       9.0000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
```

And that is actually ***not*** what I want! My `float_array` should not overwrite the other indexes from my multiple array, but only the very first index (**multiple_array[0, 0]**)

**What do I want:**

I was thinking something like this:

(Let's say this code would work like in other programming languages)

```
multiple_array[0, 0] = float_array
   FIRST_FLOAT_ARRAY       0.0000000       0.0000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
   0.0000000               0.0000000       0.0000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
   0.0000000               0.0000000       0.0000000      0.00000000      0.00000000
```

And later my `multiple_array` should look like this:

```
> multiple_array
   FIRST_FLOAT_ARRAY       SECOND_FLOAT_ARRAY       THIRD_FLOAT_ARRAY      FOURTH_FLOAT_ARRAY      FIFTH_FLOAT_ARRAY
   SIXTH_FLOAT_ARRAY       0.0000000                0.0000000              0.00000000              0.00000000
   0.0000000               0.0000000                0.0000000              0.00000000              0.00000000
```

... and so on

**What am doing with this later?**

Later I want to get these values like this:

```
current_float_array = multiple_array[0, 0]
> help, current_float_array
CURRENT_FLOAT_ARRAY               FLOAT     = Array[3, 3]

> current_float_array
   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000
   4.0000000       5.0000000       6.0000000
   7.0000000       8.0000000       9.0000000
```

Is this even possible? For me it actually doesn't matter, if my `multiple_array` would end in a PTRARR or anything else, as long as I have the result like `current_float_array` I would be happy with it.

Thanks in advance for any help!
I am looking forward for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a great job of answering your own very nicely framed question. :-) I can add some more options.

In the case where your subarrays are the same size (128x128), a common approach in IDL is to use a higher-dimensional array to contain several of them. In this case, where you want a (5x3) array of the subarrays, you could create:

```
multidim_array = FltArr(128, 128, 5, 3)
```

To access one 128x128 subarray, use, for example:

```
current_float_array = multidim_array[*, *, 0, 0]
help, current_float_array
CURRENT_FLOAT_ARRAY               FLOAT     = Array[128, 128]
```

Note that IDL drops *trailing* dimensions if they have length 1, so we get Array[128, 128] rather than Array[128, 128, 1, 1].

One note for efficiency: when you are loading data *into* this array, rather than addressing the 128x128 subarray, if you indicate the starting element only, IDL will do the assignment much more quickly. So, use:

```
multidim_array[0, 0, 0, 0] = float_array
```

rather than:

```
multidim_array[*, *, 0, 0] = float_array
```

(The general rule is that, behind the scenes, IDL takes any "*" items and expands them into a set of indices that are used to move each data element one by one. If you just give the starting element, the whole array can be copied as a block.)

Note that this is exactly what you inadvertently did in your first test above (multiple_array[0, 0] = float_array), which was not what you wanted at the time.

The multidim_array approach and your PtrArr approach will each have pros and cons when arrays are very large, where memory size and processing time may have trade-offs, but in small applications, either approach is reasonable.

Yet another way to do this (since IDL 8.1 at least) is with the LIST data type, which *would* allow the subarrays to have different sizes. In fact, an element of a list can be anything at all (like your subarrays), and you can access those entries (and even index into the subarrays) with simple array-indexing syntax. Here's a sample of what you can do, creating `a` as a list of lists:

```
IDL> a=list(list(indgen(2,3),indgen(3,4)), list(indgen(2,4)))
IDL> a
[
    [
        [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]],
        [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
    ],
    [
        [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
    ]
]
IDL> a[0]
[
    [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]],
    [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
]
IDL> a[0,1]
       0       1       2
       3       4       5
       6       7       8
       9      10      11
```

You would load your data into the list of lists like this, within a loop (sorry, not tested, but believed correct):

```
multiple_list = List()
FOR rowI = 0, 3 DO BEGIN
   row_list = List
   FOR columnI = 0, 5 DO $
      row_list.Add, GetYourFloatArrayHerePossiblyUsing(columnI, rowI)
   multiple_list.Add, row_list
ENDFOR ; rowI over all rows
```

and you could access the first array as:

```
multiple_list[0, 0]
```

and also:

```
multiple_list[0, 0, 0, 0]     ; first element of first array
multiple_list[2, 4, 127, 127] ; last element of last array
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have chosen your post as answer, because I think it is way better and in my opinion easier and faster to save float array in a multidim array :D.

I still have one little question:
With this solution you can save **float** array in a multidim array.
Is there also a similar way to save a **struct** in a multidim array? I also want first to define a multi array and then adding a struct in a certain position of the array one by one. If it is not possible to define first the multi array, would there still be a solution where I can add structs one by one?

Comment: Yes, a multidim structure array is easily done with `structArray = Replicate({myStruct, a:0, b:''}, [3, 4, 2])` and `structArray[2, 0, 1] = {a:42, b:'hi'}`. More info at [Harris docs site](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Arrays_of_Structures.html).

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer somehow by myself.
It is actually very easy. I also hope this helps other people.

**This is what you have to do:**

Instead of setting a `/FLOAT`, just set a `/PTR` in the `MAKE_ARRAY` function:

```
multiple_array = MAKE_ARRAY(5, 3, /PTR)
> multiple_array
<NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer>
<NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer>
<NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer>
```

Define your `float_array` as always:

```
float_array = FLTARR(3, 3)
;skipped setting some simple values

> float_array
   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000
   4.0000000       5.0000000       6.0000000
   7.0000000       8.0000000       9.0000000
```

**Most important part:**

Define your float array as `PTR_NEW`, so that you can save your float array in the first index.

```
multiple_array[0,0] = PTR_NEW(float_array)
> multiple_array
<PtrHeapVar1><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer>
<NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer>
<NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer><NullPointer>

> multiple_array[0,0]
<PtrHeapVar1>
```

By putting a `*` infront of your array, you will print out the content of your float array.

```
> *multiple_array[0,0]
   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000
   4.0000000       5.0000000       6.0000000
   7.0000000       8.0000000       9.0000000
```